# Данные не получены из templates

Tags: http, golang, шаблоны

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html")
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(w, err.Error())
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Lsterning on port:3000")
    http.Handle("/assets",http.StripPrefix("/assets",http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets/"))))
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
```

}

пишу по уроку. вот происходит ошибка - "Данные не получены
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"- ссылается на

```
2015/12/26 22:29:10 http: panic serving [::1]:49981: runtime error: invalid memo
ry address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 33 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0820f0160, 0x395608, 0xc082134000)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1287 +0xbc
html/template.(*Template).lookupAndEscapeTemplate(0x0, 0x7a43a0, 0x5, 0x0,    0x0,0x0)
    c:/go/src/html/template/template.go:125 +0x6a
html/template.(*Template).ExecuteTemplate(0x0, 0x26000e0, 0xc0820f0210, 0x7a43a0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/html/template/template.go:114 +0x52
main.indexHandler(0x2600058, 0xc0820f0210, 0xc08210e1c0)
    C:/gopath/src/sale/main.go:11 +0x118
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x83e590, 0x2600058, 0xc0820f0210, 0xc08210e1c0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1422 +0x41
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc0820563c0, 0x2600058, 0xc0820f0210, 0xc08210e1c0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1699 +0x184
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc082004300, 0x2600058, 0xc0820f0210, 0xc08210e1c0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1862 +0x1a5
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0820f0160)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1361 +0xbf5
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x3fd
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что я сразу делал `Build and Run`,
а нужно сначала только `Build` и потом запускать.

Answer (score 0):

При ошибке `template.ParseFiles` не делается `return` и вызывается `t.ExecuteTemplate` с `t` равным `nil`.

И еще `fmt.Fprintf(w. err.Error())` - это не валидный код, после `w` надо запятую, и `Fprint` вместо `Fprintf`.

Comment: спасибо, но я пробовал и с return, ошибка всё равно происходит

Comment: постарался исправить